# Load element in frame of frameset from another frame using javascript

Tags: html, frame

I'm using frame and frameset for my page. To access an element in a frame from another frame, I used this js code:

```
parent.frames['frame1'].document.getElementById('inputfield1');
```

But it just works well with Webkit. It's failed on Firefox. I think my code is wrong. 
How could I make it work on Firefox ?

```
<frameset id="fset" rows="60%,40%" frameborder="1"> 
     <frame name="frame1" src="...">
     <frame name="frame2" src="...">
</frameset>
```

Comment: do you have a good reason to be using frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following into head section of your main page.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('frame1');
        var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var your_input_field = innerDoc.getElementById(inputfield1);
    }
</script>
```

You can then use `parent.doSomething();` inside the frames to call doSomething() of main page which can reach both frames.